# Convergence of a Series Absolutely for Almost Every Real Number

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

> Consider two sequences of real numbers $\{a_n\}$ and $\{r_n\}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_n| < \infty.$ Prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{\strut |x-r_n|}}$$ converges absolutely for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

We are asked to give a measure-theoretic proof of this fact. We know Fubini's Theorem about interchanging the order of integration; however, I am not sure how this is supposed to help us. Could someone provide a push in the right direction or a hint as to how to solve this problem?

Comment: Let $f_n(x) = \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{|x-r_n|}}.$ Given an $\varepsilon > 0,$ consider the set $C_{\varepsilon} = \{r \in \mathbb{R} : |r_n - r| < \varepsilon \text{ i.o} \}.$ Clayton, you claim that this set has measure zero and that its complement is precisely the set on which the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x)$ converges?

Comment: @Clayton, consider the case when $r_n = \sin n.$ We have that $r_n$ has infinitely many cluster points, so this argument does not seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

$$\int_{-1}^1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt {|x-r_n|}}\, dx =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt {|x-r_n|}}\, dx$$ $$ \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{|a_n|}{\sqrt {|x|}}\, dx =  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 4|a_n|< \infty.$$

Comment: @kobe Just look at the graph of $1/\sqrt {|x|}.$ You get a bigger integral if the singularity is in the middle.

Comment: Why should your inequality be true?

Comment: What is $r_n$? Your inequality seems to require $\sqrt {|x|}\; \geq \sqrt {|x-r_n|}$.

Comment: We are not given any conditions on $r_n.$

Comment: We are simply given that $r_n$ is a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet   What I'm claiming it that $\int_{-1}^1 1/\sqrt {|x-x_0|}\, dx$ is maximized when $x_0=0.$ This is actually an easy argument.

Comment: Right . I see.......